# netty EpollServerSocketChannel SO_BACKLOG

Tags: netty, socketchannel

I'm using netty 4.0.36-Final and I'm trying to set the SO_BACKLOG option on a channel. My simple goal is to have a server that refuse all the connections.
In order to have this I thought that would have been enough setting AUTO_READ to false and SO_BACKLOG to 0.

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(serverConfiguration.getParentGroup(), serverConfiguration.getChildGroup()).channel(EpollServerSocketChannel.class).childHandler(channelIntializer);
```

I'm setting the SO_BACKLOG option as a childOption but as soon as I send requests to the server I see this message:

```
WARN  io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap - Unknown channel option: SO_BACKLOG=0
```

I debug a little and the reason why is unknown is because the child.config() method return an instance of io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannelConfig
instead of io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollServerChannelConfig

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: can you add the code where you set the config option ?

Comment: found... I was setting it as a childOption instead of an option